# Differentiate the Function: $y=x^x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$y=x^x$

Use $\frac{d}{dx}(a^x)=a^x \ln a$

My answer is: $x^x \ln x$

The book has the answer as $x^x\ (1+ \ln\ x)$

Am I missing a step?

Comment: $a$ is meant to be a constant.

Comment: try $x^x = \exp(x \log(x))$.

Comment: to make a sense : look at behavior of two function $$2^n \\vs\\n^n$$

Comment: Can somebody tell me why this was downvoted? Just so that I don't make the same mistake later.

Comment: @JeanYasir, feel free to ask questions like these (although with more appropriate tagging and formatting) the downvote (imo) was not warranted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take logs first so that you have $$\ln y =x\ln x$$

Then $$\frac 1y \frac{dy}{dx}=1+\ln x$$

And the result follows

Answer (score 4):

If $f(x) = x^x$ then taking the natural logarithm of both sides and making use of the power rule for logarithms yields $$\ln f(x) = x \ln x$$ Implicitly differentiating with respect to $x$ gives us $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \ln x + 1$$

So, by multiplying through by $f(x)$, we have $$\bbox[10px, border: blue 1px solid]{f'(x) = x^x(\ln x + 1).}$$

The issue with your method is that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}a^x = a^x \ln a$ holds only when $a$ is constant, in this case we have $a$ as some variable $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$(x^x)'=(e^{x\ln x})'=x^x(1\ln x+x\frac1x)$.

Incidentally, if we add (wrong) solutions $(x^x)'=(a^x)'=a^x\ln a$ and $(x^x)'=(x^a)'=a \cdot x^{a-1}$ for $a=x$, we obtain the correct result. :-)

Comment: On the last part, close, but not quite - $(x^a)'=ax^{a-1}$, and besides, $x^x\ln(x)+x.x^x=x^x(\ln(x)+x)$, not $x^x(\ln(x)+1)$.

Comment: The derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$. How did you calculate your third step?

Comment: @Donkey_2009 Lapsus calami. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @SunnyBlack $(e^{f(x)})'=e^{f(x)}\cdot f'(x)$.

Comment: If you're interested, that's not a coincidence! If you define $f(x,y)=x^{y}$, then $df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy=\log y x^{y}dx+yx^{y-1}dy$

Comment: @Przemysław Scherwentke when I use that formula I get $e^{x\ ln\ x}\cdot x\cdot \frac{1}{x}+lnx\ e^x$

Comment: @SunnyBlack No. $(e^{x\ln x})'=e^{x\ln x}\cdot (x\ln x)'$.

Comment: And the derivative of $(x\ln x)'$ is? Wouldn't I use the product rule?

Comment: @SunnyBlack $(f(x)\cdot g(x))'=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$. Here $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=\ln x$ and the result is computed in my answer. You should notice, that $f\cdot g$ and $f\circ g$ have different meaning (if I correctly understand your problem).

Answer (score 0):

taking the logarithm of both sides we get
$$\ln(y)=x\ln(x)$$ differentiating with respect to $x$ we obtain
$$\frac{1}{y}y'=\ln(x)+1$$ multiplying by $y$ you will get the result.

Answer (score 0):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Let $y=x^x\;,$ Now Taking $\log_{e}$ on both side, we get

$$\displaystyle \log_{e}(y) = \log_{e}(x)^x = x\cdot \log_{e}(x)$$

Now Differentiate both side $\bf{w.r.t}$ $x\;,$ We get

$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{y}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx} = x\cdot \frac{1}{x}+\log_{e}(x)\cdot 1\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = y(1+\log_{e}(x)) = x^x\cdot (1+\log_{e}(x)).$$

Answer (score 0):

> *Am I missing a step ?*

Of course ! You are missing $(x^n)'=n~x^{n-1}$. *Add* this to your initial *incomplete* result, then replace *n* by *x* — just like you also replaced *a* by *x* — and see what you get ! ;-$)$