# Differentiate the Function: $y=\sqrt{x^x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$y=\sqrt{x^x}$

How do I convert this into a form that is workable and what indicates that I should do so?

Anyway, I tried this method of logging both sides of the equation but I don't know if I am right.

$\ln\ y=\sqrt{x} \ln\ x$

$\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot \frac{1}{y}=\sqrt{x}\ \frac{1}{x} +\ln\ x\ \frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

$\sqrt{x}\cdot (\sqrt{x}\ \frac{1}{x} +\ln\ x \ \frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}})$

Comment: Apply chain rule to the answer you got there: [Differentiate the Function: $y=x^x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371589/differentiate-the-function-y-xx)

Comment: We have $\ln y=\frac{1}{2}x\ln x$.

Comment: You can also write $y=x^{x/2}$ and then $\ln y=\frac x2\ln x$.

Comment: +1 for "logging" the equation. I'm imagining the exponents being cut down with a chainsaw... :)

Comment: @FundThmCalculus Chainsaws are a valuable part of any mathematical training

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That way could work though you made some mistakes, but an easier way shifts the square root to a fractional exponent.

$$\begin{align}
y&=\sqrt{x^x} \\[2ex]
 &= \left(x^x\right)^{1/2} \\[2ex]
 &= x^{x/2} \\[2ex]
\ln y&= \ln x^{x/2} \\[2ex]
 &= \frac x2\ln x \\[2ex]
\frac{dy}{dx}\frac 1y &=\frac 12\ln x+\frac x2\frac 1x \\[2ex]
 &= \frac 12\ln x+\frac 12 \\[2ex]
\frac{dy}{dx} &= y\left(\frac 12\ln x+\frac 12 \right) \\[2ex]
 &= \sqrt{x^x}\left(\frac 12\ln x+\frac 12 \right) \\[2ex]
 &= \frac 12\sqrt{x^x}\left(\ln x+1 \right)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

All functions of type $u^v$ are defined with:
$$u^v=\mathrm e^{v\ln u}.\enspace\text{Here:}\quad \sqrt{x^x}=\mathrm e^{\frac12 x\ln x}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Square both sides:

$$y^{2}=x^{x}$$
Then upon differentiating
$$2y y' = (1+\ln x)x^{x}$$
From which
$$y'=\frac{1}{2y}(1+\ln x)x^{x} \qquad (x \neq 0)$$
Giving
$$y' = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^{x}}}(1+\ln x)x^{x} $$
Thus
$$y'=\frac{1}{2}(1+\ln x)\sqrt{x^{x}}$$

Comment: You left out a $2$ in the denominator in your next-to-last line.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Good man! Fixed and now looks complete. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that are not quite right, moreover taking the logarithm might not be the best choice (but it seems you are supposed to do this).

- Note $\ln \sqrt{u}= \frac{1}{2} \ln u$, so your first line is incorrect.
- In the second you dropped an $x$ after the $\ln$.
- In the third you took wrongly $\sqrt{x}$ for $y$.

Answer (score 0):

let $f(x)=\sqrt{x^x}$ then we obtain $\ln(f(x))=\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^x)=\frac{1}{2}x\ln(x)$ and after this we have $$\frac{1}{f}f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}\ln(x)+\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You made a few simple mistakes, most notably, you got the log wrong:

$$\ln y = \frac12 x \ln x$$

Differentiating then gives:

$$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac12\ln x+\frac12$$

And hence:

$$y'=y\left(\frac12\ln x +\frac12\right)=\frac12\sqrt{x^x}\left(\ln x+1\right)$$